# Google Annotation chart: Could it be possible to reverse the Y-axis?

Tags: charts, annotations, google-visualization

I am working with the project that need Google Annotation Chart to show my data. And I have a problem like below.

My problem:
I would like to show the reverse value on the Y-axis.
What I mean is: the bigger the value is down and vice versa (the smaller the value is up)

I try to test all the option at the support docs but it still did not work
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotationchart

Option:

```
...
 vAxis: {direction: -1} // This works on line chart but not annotation chart
...
```

or somethings like

```
...
max: -200000, // this won't work and it's just keep the value not minus
min: 200000
...
```

This is my test code that forked from the docs page
https://jsfiddle.net/lecaoquochung/dsmgL9wj/2/

Could anyone help me to answer my problem? (Could it be possible to reverse the Y-axis now and later?)

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. I have updated the [testcode](https://jsfiddle.net/lecaoquochung/dsmgL9wj/2/) chart

Solution: add the chart to the option (get support from Googler)

```
 chart : {vAxis: {direction: -1}},
```

- Memo: Wonder that something updated in the API or just syntax (Because there is no description for chart option on graph docs pages)

Hope this help for anyone meet the same problem.